# Is payload integrity encryption important for API?

Tags: php, json, api, encryption, md5

Do we need to encrypt and sign the payload to prevent tampering and ensure integrity ?

**Assuming we have JWT bearer in the header and the API is secured with HTTPS**.

Given an example of a payload that will be sent to the API that changes data of a user profile.

```
{"name":"bob","age":10,"gender":"m"}
```

Do we need to do a md5 ( payload + private key ) for a signed payload ? 
Example:

```
md5(namebobage10genderm_private_key)
md5 code = fdd5a4a41fc0ab84d4792fa8b08d8e17
```

The new payload would be

```
{"name":"bob","age":10,"gender":"m","signed":"fdd5a4a41fc0ab84d4792fa8b08d8e17"}
```

When the server receives the API call , it will also do the md5 encryption of the payload and compares the signed value in order to ensure integrity.

Please let me know your thoughts regarding this and do we really need this ? As we already have HTTPS for the API and JWT to authenticate the user calling the api.

**EDIT**

This is quite subjective , the api call is still vulnerable to man in the middle attack , where the api call can be intercepted via proxy before it hits HTTPS . As long as the attacker does not know the algorithm, whatever data being modified during the intercept will be rejected at the server as a signed payload was sent alongside with the payload to verify at the server end.

Please enlighten me . Thank you

Comment: Just use SSL (HTTPS). Why even consider this home-grown scheme?

Comment: Https ensures integrity as well as privacy https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS

Comment: @JamesKPolk Because some things are done via GET and you don't want legitimate users to be able to fiddle around with the parameters they see in an attempt to get info on other users.  Multiple levels of security are a GOOD thing.  Things like SSL keep out a 3rd party.  Things like message/payload signing keep data sane

Answer (score 1):

> Is payload integrity encryption important for API?

Integrity and confidentiality are two separate properties.

Encryption provides confidentiality. Some encryption modes also provide authentication. We call these **authenticated encryption**, **IND-CCA3**, and/or **AEAD**, depending on some details.

[You want authenticated encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly).

> Do we need to do a md5 ( payload + private key ) for a signed payload ? Example:

Don't use MD5 for anything. It's been broken for many years now.

> When the server receives the API call , it will also do the md5 encryption of the payload and compares the signed value in order to ensure integrity.

[MD5 isn't an *encryption* function](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded). It's a hash function.

---

The easiest answer to this situation that won't leave your app totally insecure is: [Use PASETO instead of JWT](https://paseto.io) and then you don't need to anguish over whether or not you need to encrypt, sign, or both.

`v1.local` and `v2.local` provide authenticated encryption. Use one of the two (v2 is better, v1 is for compatibility). You don't need to do anything on top of PASETO to make it secure, it already provides integrity guarantees.

Further reading: *[PASETO is a Secure Alternative to the JOSE Standards (JWT, etc.)](https://paragonie.com/blog/2018/03/paseto-platform-agnostic-security-tokens-is-secure-alternative-jose-standards-jwt-etc)*  (Disclaimer: I'm the author.)

PASETO doesn't obviate the need for HTTPS, but you've already expressed that you're using HTTPS, so, just keep doing that.